# Changing values in list between two points

Tags: python

I have a list

```
list = [3, 3, 3,..., 3]
```

and only want to change the values of elements between point A (list[0]) and B (list[-1])

so

```
function(list,2 , 1, -1) 

>[3,2,2,2,3]
```

Comment: so you need to change all element values? because list[0] is first item and list [-1] is last item and elements between them are all elements please edit your question and add more information to help you.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili between 0 and -1 is everything except first and last, as it's confirmed by the example.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

You can change a sub-list by assigning to a slice, e.g:

```
L = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
L[1:-1] = [2] * (len(L) - 2)
```

or:

```
L[1:-1] = itertools.repeat(2, len(L)-2)
```

<strike>to avoid an intermediate list</strike> - I take it back, as @juanpa.arrivillaga noticed, that will make a list anyway.

Comment: Just to note, it won't actually avoid an intermediate list, `list.__setitem__` makes a list out of it anyway.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, just was checking the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L610), do I understand correct that it happens in `PySequence_Fast`?

Answer (score -1):

So logic is that we will keep intact `btwlower_` and `btwupper_` index of `list_` and replace all other with `replace_`. This can be done by taking that section which we want to update:

```
list_[btwlower_: btwupper_]]
```

**CODE :**

```
list_ = [3, 3, 3,..., 3]

def func(list_, replace_, btwlower_, btwupper_):
    l = [replace_ for i in list_[btwlower_: btwupper_]]
    return [list_[btwlower_]] + l + [list_[btwupper_]]

print(func(list_, 2, 1, -1))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, this will work dynamically.

```
def function(ls,n,place1,place2):
     a = []
     for i in range(len(ls)):
          if place1!=i and place2 !=i:
               a.append(n)
          else:
               a.append(ls[i])
     return a
```